# How to propose a "Subset operations" algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sum, combinations, subset, digits

I am working on this problem:

> Given a set (or multiset) of positive numbers, find all the numbers which are combination of some elements from the set. Combination means sum, subtraction or product.

For example, if A = {3, 4, 7}, we have to find 3, 4, 7, 3+4, 3*4, |3-4|, 3+7, 3*7, |3-7|, 4+7, 4*7, |4-7|, 3+4+7, 3+4*7, 3+|4-7|, |3+7-4|, |3*7-4|...

Fortunately, our set is not bigger than 10 numbers, but I am not able to find an algorithm to find all the solutions. You can see this problem as the "subset sum problem" (given a set A and an integer k, say if A contains a subset whose elements sum k) but instead of sum, it is a combination of operators, and we want to find all the possible k-values.

I tried but too many possible solutions are missing. It is not correct but I only want to show the essence of my idea: (C++ code)

```
vector<int> analyze (vector<int> v) {

    if (v.size()==1)    return v[0];
    vector<int> result;
    vector<int> u = analyze(v.delete(1));   //u = analyze(v[1], ..., v[n])
    for (int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++) {
        result.add(v[0] + u[i]);
        result.add(v[0] * u[i]);
        result.add(abs(v[0] - u[i]));
    }
    result.add(v[0]);
    return result + u;  //Union
}
```

If A = {a, b, c, d} this function will not return:

a*(c+b*d)

(a*b)+(c*d)

|a-d|+b

**Anyone knows about how to approach this problem, or any bibliography which helps?**

Comment: Indeed, there is no way to represent the `a*b+c*d` here. You may try running recursion for every two possible subsets, not for just the subsets `{v0}` and `{v1, v2, ..., vn}`. If that turns out too slow, use memoization.

Comment: The brute force approach takes advantage of [postfix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/postfix_notation) to eliminate the need for parentheses. The search space is every permutation of `N` numbers followed by every possible combination of `N-1` operators. For example with the array `{3,4,7}` there are six permutations, and nine combinations of operators giving 54 possibilities. But then you need to choose 2 of the 3 numbers, which gives `3*2*3 = 18` additional possibilities. And finally choosing 1 of the 3 numbers adds 3 more. So you have a total of 75 possibilities to compute.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to generate all parse trees (there is no need to do it explicitly).

Let's assume that we have a subset of the initial set. If there is one number, we just return it. Otherwise, we iterate over all operations. For a fixed operation, we iterate over all ways to partition the set into two subsets. We can compute all possible expressions for the subsets recursively and then combine them using this operation.

To take into account the fact that we are allowed not to use some of the numbers, we can run this algorithm for all subsets of the given set.